# Test variable if its string or not

Tags: shell, string, variable, test

I'm writing a script which will have some arguments and so I am using `getopts`
but i want to solve the problem with one argument.

I use a switch, for example `-d`, and I want the argument for `-d` will be the path to a directory, like `./work`.

I want to test the user's input for a string or path, not a number. Is there any solution to solve this problem? I want to solve it with something like:

```
If (test)
  then echo it is string
else 
  echo it is not string
```

Comment: A number is a valid directory name. I would not do any such check.

Answer (score 1):

Every variable is a string.

If you want to distinguish “is a number” from “is not a number”, test that.

```
while getopts d: OPTLET; do
  case "$OPTLET" in
    d)
      case "$OPTARG" in
        *[!0-9]*) echo 1>&2 "Non-numeric argument to -d, stopping."; exit 2;;
        *) number_of_foo=$OPTARG;;
      esac;;
  esac
done
```

It isn't clear from your question whether this is what you really want. A number *is* a string. `123` is a valid file name. So if the argument to `-d` is supposed to be a potential file name, there is no validation to do. Any sequence of characters is a potentially valid file name.

Comment: The only caveats to the valid file name is that the slash character can only be used as a directory separator, not part of a file name, and `NUL` (aka `\0`) can't be part of any path or file name. Handling arbitrary paths is difficult.

Comment: @l0b0 Right, a [pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266) can contain any byte except NUL (including `/` at arbitrary positions) while a [filename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_169) can contain any character except `/` and NUL. There are very few contexts where a command line argument would have to be a filename (sans directory) rather than a pathname.